# Without using VBA, create a formula to flag column results between n and n+1 parameters

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement

Without using vba, can a excel formula replicate the flags in column c? These flags are created from column b, the column b cells between a values of 1.

[image: Table]

Tried various if, index and match functions but could not get it to work accurately

Comment: This is the same question as your other one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77298725/can-i-sum-values-within-a-column-between-certain-starting-and-end-values. Does it really need two separate questions?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
=IF(
    AND(
        SUMIF($B2:$B$2,"=1")>0,
        SUMIF($B4:$B$10,"=1")>0,
        B3<>1),
    "Flag",
    "")

=IF(
    AND(
        SUMIF(R[-1]C2:R2C2,"=1")>0,
        SUMIF(R[1]C2:R10C2,"=1")>0,
        RC[-1]<>1),
    "Flag",
    "")
```

Basically, if there's a 1 above and a 1 below and I'm not on a one then "flag".